# saving utm values from url parameters using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, utm

Given an example URL:

```
https://examplesite.com/?utm_source=google&utm_source_id=1234&utm_medium=example&utm_campaign=secured&utm_term=get&utm_content=other
```

I am trying to save my UTM values to hidden fields in my html:

```html
<input id="campaign" name="campaign" class="meta-form-data" type="text" value="" hidden />
<input id="source_id" name="source_id" class="meta-form-data" type="text" value="" hidden />
<input id="source" name="source" class="meta-form-data" type="text" value="" hidden />
<input id="channel" name="channel" class="meta-form-data" type="text" value="" hidden />
<input id="keyword" name="keyword" class="meta-form-data" type="text" value="" hidden />
<input id="content" name="content" class="meta-form-data" type="text" value="" hidden />
```

When I save my utm values from url I use this function:

```js
    function ParseTrackingUrl() {
        var utm_source = getUrlParameter('utm_source');
        var utm_source_id = getUrlParameter('utm_source_id');
        var utm_medium = getUrlParameter('utm_medium');
        var utm_campaign = getUrlParameter('utm_campaign');
        var utm_term = getUrlParameter('utm_term');
        var utm_content = getUrlParameter('utm_content');

        jQuery("#source").val(utm_source);
        jQuery("#source_id").val(utm_source_id);
        jQuery("#campaign").val(utm_campaign);
        jQuery("#channel").val(utm_medium);
        jQuery("#keyword").val(utm_term);
        jQuery("#content").val(utm_content);
    }
```

Then each utm value is obtained from the URL:

```js
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
};
```

The `utm_source` and `utm_source_id` are not saving correctly. `utm_source_id` is empty and `utm_source` is obtaining the `source_id` value. I'm not sure how this is happening. All the other utm values save fine.

Comment: Your code works fine, so long as the functions are declared in the correct order: https://jsfiddle.net/jxcng5yr/. Please check the console for errors.

Comment: can you see any reason why my source would populate the source_id?

Comment: Not given the code and URL example you've provided.